# RESTful Webservices Integration With Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, web-services, hibernate, rest

I am in the process of learning RESTful Webservice.

I am using Hibernate 4 and Spring 3. I would like to know if I need to implement REST services, I call the service implementation class EmployeeServiceImpl from MyController class? And invoke get, put delete methods of REST from client layers?

If Spring is used which REST project can be used  CXF or Jersey?
What is the best approach in creating Controller class for REST services?

**Service Implementation class**

```
@Transactional
@Service(value = "empService")
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

@Inject
EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

@Override
public List<Emp> findAllEmployees() {
return getEmployeeDAO().findAllEmployees();
}
```

**DAO Implementation class**

```
@Repository("empDAO")
public class EmployeeDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Emp> implements EmployeeDAO {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public List<Emp> findAllEmployees() {
CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
cq.select(cq.from(Emp.class));
return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but you might want to seriously consider using Spring Data REST with Spring Data JPA as an alternative to what you're doing. You don't even need to code DAO implementation classes; you get them for free.

Comment: @JonathanW If I am using Spring Data JPA then do I need to have Hibernate?

Comment: Hibernate is an implementor of JPA, so you'd need to include it runtime. But that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAX-RS implementations (RESTeasy, Jersey) are fully J2E, that means you don't need Spring to work with. But you can use it any way.

Here a simple example of a service, decorated with the right annotations, and then don't need any Controller :

```
package com.mkyong.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

}
```

Source : http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Indeed, the magic inside this JSR (331) is that you don't need Controllers, it will map automatically calls from

```
/context/{defined_sub_context}/{entity}/{params}
```

to

```
/org.corp.package.app.services.class
```

if class is decorated with @Path("{entity}) and a method @Path("/{param}")

Great, isn't it ?

Comment: Jean thanks for this. Would like to know if I would like to invoke `findAllEmployees()` method in Service Implementation class, how could I do this?

Comment: HMmm .. it doesn't sound very clear. You want to call EmployeeDAO.findAllEmployees() from your service, using Spring ?

Comment: Jean I think I made it confusing. My doubt is how can I call findAllEmployees() using REST? Even if I am not using Spring as you have mentioned.

Comment: Do you have any framework for the presentation tier ? If you just have Servlet (what I really doubt ;)), implements doGet, doPost, doDelete or doPut methods and call findAllEmployees from there (and declare any new servlet in your web.xml). If you have frameworks like SpringMVC, Tapestry, Struts or anything else, code a controller  and then follow the framework conventions, but you may probably not be RESTful (because it won't deal PUT or DELETE and may confuse POST and GET). If you really want to be RESTful don't code any controller, just put JAX-RS annotations on your service, like above.